# Making the iPhone work with stripped down Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, iphone, itunes, nlite

this is my first time posting here and I have a really specific question.

I have an ASUS eee 901 running Windows XP Home.  I had everything working well, but then I decided to improve performance by moving Windows to the smaller but faster internal SSD.

I used Nlite to strip down Windows, following the instructions here:
http://wiki.eeeuser.com/howto:nlitexp

I now have a very lightweight installation of XP home with SP3 and all the current updates.  Almost everything is working really well.  I have installed iTunes and I CAN sync with no problems.

However, each time I plug in my iPhone 3GS (latest firmware), Windows tries and fails to install drivers.  The Found New Hardware Wizard launches, but nothing I do will make it complete successfully, with the result that the iphone does not show up in Windows as removable storage, or as a camera.  When I launch the Camera and Scanner Wizard, it shows only my webcam, not the iphone.

I have verified that I have the following files in place:

- Windows\System32\ptpusb.dll (regsvr32 successful)

  Windows\System32\ptpusd.dll (entry point not found, can not be registered)

  Windows\System32\usbaaplrc.dll (entry point not found, can not be registered)

  Windows\System32\drivers\usbaapl.sys

  Windows\System32\drivers\usbscan.sys>

  Windows\System32\drivers\usbstor.sys

Does anyone know if some other file is required or if there's some other element preventing this from working?

**Edit** (From posted answer)

I did select Cameras & Camcorders, and my webcam is working fine for video & still capture.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two files which are corrupt, not available or otherwise unusable (namely ptpusd.dll and usbaaplrc.dll). You will have to repair those first.

Get your 'normal' XP CD and boot from it.

At a certain point, it will give you the option to press R to go to the recovery console. Do this.

After that, you have to copy those files from the CD to the appropriate directory on your SSD. A little Googleing will show you how to do that. Adjust any commands to your situation, of course ;-)

If all the output shows the files as working, there's a very good chance your iPhone will work too.

Answer (score 0):

When you were creating the stripped down version using Nlite and you were at this step:

[image]

Did you make sure to select "Cameras and Camcorders"? If you didn't do this it probably left the functionality out. Windows keeps asking to install it because whenever you plug it in, it tries to do it and fails.

Comment: I did select Cameras & Camcorders, and my webcam is working fine for video & still capture.